# How mix 3D Data from Google Map and one's 3D object?

Tags: google-maps, 3d

Is it possible to add some 3D object in the 3D maps from Google ?
Which tools should I use (never used 3D modelling tools but I'm motivated :)

Here is the picture that triggered my question : 
[image]

Comment: Try using [Sketchup](http://www.sketchup.com/) -which is free and follow this [tutorial on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ECzPdL9unxE)